# Flutter audio player.play function not working

Tags: flutter

I'm working on a Flutter application where I want a sound to play when a button is clicked. However, despite clicking the button, I don't hear any sound, and there are no error messages in the console.

```
class DrumMachine extends StatelessWidget {
  final player = AudioPlayer();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: TextButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              await player.play(AssetSource("bip.wav"));
            },
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
name: d
description: "A new Flutter project."
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.2.3 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  audioplayers: ^5.2.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
     - assets/
```

Comment: In what platform are you running in (Android, iOS, web, Windows)?

Comment: Running in  Android @enzo

Answer (score 0):

You incorrectly point to your asset. In the `AssetSource` you put `bip.wav`. This would mean that your audio file is in the Flutter project root, next to your `pubspec.yaml`. Because of the `assets/` you put in the `flutter.assets` in your pubspec, I assume the audio file is actually in `assets/bip.wav` relative to your package root.

Use `assets/bip.wav` as the path in your `AssetSource`.